# Function determining the length of text, usable where something with internal units (e.g. "em") is expected

Tags: boxes, lengths

Is there a way to define a function `\horizontallengthof` returning the length of a piece of text in internal units? I would like to be able to use it anywhere where something of that sort is required, for example like `p{\horizontallengthof{this particular piece of text}}` (in a table specification) or `\hspace{\horizontallengthof{this particular piece of text}}`.

---

I am hesitant to post a particular use case, since I am interested in a generic solution instead of workarounds for particular situations. But here is one (with `calc`'s `\widthof` standing in for `\horizontallengthof`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0em}@{\hspace{1.0em}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}
  \(\bullet\) & \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \\
  \(\bullet\) & \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{\(\bullet\)}}@{\hspace{1.0em}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}
  \(\bullet\) & \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \\
  \(\bullet\) & \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{\(\bullet\)}}@{\hspace{1.0em-\widthof{\(\bullet\)}}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}
  \(\bullet\) & \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \\
  \(\bullet\) & \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With the suggestion to add `fixltx2e`, this compiles properly, but I'd like the second table to have the same appearance (spacing-wise) as the first one, while giving me no `Overfull \hbox` warnings. Table 3 is a failed attempt at achieving this.

One reason why I didn't initially post this is that I didn't want any potential workarounds to this distract from a general (and imho needed) solution.

Comment: `\usepackage{calc}` and then `\hspace{\widthof{text}}`

Comment: Hmm, if I try `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{calc} \begin{document} a\hspace{\widthof{some text}}b \end{document}`, I get a `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error.

Comment: Uh! I've been too confident in `calc`. :( However, `\widthof` can be used in the argument of `\parbox` and for `p`-columns.

Comment: @egreg I think your confidence in calc is correct, but LaTeX let you down

Comment: @egreg Okay, and if I want to be able to use `\widthof` for something like `\(\bullet\)`? See my added minimal example.

Comment: fragile command, moving argument add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` and then `\(` is robust (or you could just use `$` which is robust anyway)

Comment: @egreg I could make a separate question for that (maybe I should?) but see my edited (and final) motivating example.

Comment: using widthof in the array preamble is massively inefficient you will redo the box and measure every row and then all you are doing is making a box as big as its known content. Why not simply use @{\(\bullet\)} and insert a bullet every row. Or use `l`.

Comment: l will of course be wider than p{0pt} as l makes a column as wide as the bullet but p{0pt} makes a zero width column with the bullet over-printing the following column.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l@{\qquad}l}
  \rlap{\(\bullet\)} & \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \  \rlap{\(\bullet\)} & \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\end{tabular}`

Comment: Btw, with egreg's `\Hspace`, the following gives the desired result *and* no overfull `\hbox`es: `\begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{\(\bullet\)}}@{\Hspace{1.0em-\widthof{\(\bullet\)}}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I wasn't quite aware that it was *overprinting* the second column. I see, I see. The reason why I came up with this particular example in the first place was because (if I remember correctly) I was unhappy with the (imho huge) added vertical space everywhere when you deal with bulleted lists. So I simply made it a table and put it inside `memoir`'s `\begin{Spacing}{1} \noindent ... \end{Spacing}`. I hope my motivation makes sense: this is really about emulating ordinary `itemize`, whose vertical spacing I'm *very* unhappy with.

Comment: @egreg (and David): Anything else I need to know about package loading order for `calc`? The documentation doesn't specify that it needs to be before or after certain other packages.

Comment: It shouldn't clash with any package, it is part of the core (but you don't need it for this anyway:-)

Comment: arrggggggggggggg!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   every single space in a latex list is a user settable parameter, if you don't like them, change them. " I hope my motivation makes sense: " that would be a no then:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By the way, using `memoir` *necessitates* `$\bullet$` instead of `\(\bullet\)`, even with `fixltx2e`; I have no clue why. This might be something to pass on to those in charge (if you're not one of them).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About the "argh" comment :-) You might be lucky: I might actually have remembered incorrectly. Sorry about that :-) *Actually* the thing was that I was trying to emulate a bulleted list (`itemize`) with horizontal alignment (see that there are two equations in each row). So that really did necessitate a tabular; I didn't want to fiddle with tabs and `itemize` to get that result. I did in fact manage to create a `\newenvironment{mytightlist}` (with most parameters set to `0pt`), which addresses my vertical spacing preference. My previous comment about what motivated me was wrong.

Comment: Btw the reason for the particular `\hspace{1.0em}\quad` in my example was to have it match up with earlier lists. (That's why I didn't first want to post this example, because it'd too confusing to explain, apparently it's confusing to myself ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmm arguably this is a `calc` and/or LaTeX bug.

using `calc` and `\widthof` would work in most of the places you mention (as in LaTeX2e
such places explicitly changed to use `\setlength` internally so that they would work with `calc`. However `\hspace` appears to have escaped that conversion, the following patch fixes that.....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc} 

\makeatletter
\def\@hspace#1{\begingroup\setlength\dimen@{#1}\hskip\dimen@\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 a\hspace{\widthof{some text}}b 

\end{document}
```

---

The above answers the original question, but the later edits have clarified that this is not needed at all.  `\widthof` is a relatively expensive operation and doing every row just to make space to insert the same text you measured is really just torturing your computer for no real gain. The formulation in the second table matches the version you gave in the first without the over full boxes and without measuring anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0em}@{\hspace{1.0em}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}
  \(\bullet\) & \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \\
  \(\bullet\) & \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace\tabcolsep\rlap{$\bullet$}\hspace{1.0em}\quad}l@{\qquad}l}
   \(x = y\) & \(z = w\) \\
   \(a = b\) & \(c = d\) \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you're on the LaTeX team, should someone (eg me) still report a bug? To whom? (See [this question of mine on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3326/14996) about the reporting of bugs.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure yes well you could report it, just type `latex latexbug` and follow the instructions. Not sure we'd change it (it is computationally very expensive and might break some non standard uses of hspace) but it could at least be documented.

Comment: Done. (I've used the webform instead.)

Comment: To others: **Please see egreg's answer, which also gets credit and complements this one.**

Comment: @LoverofStructure Thanks, the mail server had got stuck, we kicked it and the bug report is now listed  as http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4209

Answer (score 7):

`calc` patches some of the main LaTeX constructs so that an extended syntax is accepted. However, it doesn't do the same for `\hspace`.

The command `\widthof` can be used in `\setlength` and in the argument to `\parbox`, `minipage` and also in the `p`-column specifier.

You can get a version of `\hspace` that works with `\widthof`, but I wouldn't use it as a replacement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\newlength\Hspacelen
\NewDocumentCommand{\Hspace}{sm}
 {\setlength\Hspacelen{#2}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\hspace*{\Hspacelen}}
    {\hspace{\Hspacelen}}%
 }

\makeatletter
%\def\Hspace#1#{\@Hspace{#1}}
%\def\@Hspace#1#2{\setlength\@tempdima{#2}\hspace#1{\@tempdima}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

a\Hspace{\widthof{text}}b

\Hspace*{\widthof{text}}ab
\end{document}
```

The commented version is a faster alternative.

However, since you probably don't want a space that disappears at page breaks, the faster method is to say

```
\leavevmode\hphantom{text}
```

Don't forget `\leavevmode` at the start of a paragraph; it's irrelevant if `\hphantom` is in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: +1 I think you two found the "right" answer jointly (see comment thread to original question above). This was a very close call. You ultimately have more details on the actual question. It won't hurt for people to upvote yours equally.

Answer (score 3):

Does `\wd` works ?

E.g:

```
\newsavebox{\mymeasure} % only 1 time, in the preamble
```

Then:

```
\sbox{\mymeasure}{this particular piece of text}
X\hspace{\wd\mymeasure}X
```

<strike>So, to have just 1 command, in your preamble:</strike>

```
\newsavebox{\mymeasure}
\newcommand{\measure}[1]{\sbox{\mymeasure}{#1}\wd\mymeasure}
```

Usage:

```
X\hspace{\measure{this particular piece of texte}}X
```

Comment: No :-( Here is minimal example code: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} X\hspace{\wd\mbox{some text}}X \end{document}`

Comment: Ok, `\wd` seems to operate on box only; I have modified my answer

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Now if I try `\documentclass{article} \newsavebox{\mymeasure} \newcommand{\measure}[1]{\sbox{\mymeasure}{#1}\wd\mymeasure} \begin{document} a\hspace{\measure{some text}}b \end{document}`, that gives me a "Missing number, treated as zero." error.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Of course it doesn't work this way. Box assignment `\sbox` cannot be in expandable context, and TeX tries to expand everything when it is looking for dimensions. You would have to use the first option suggested by Lionel: place `\sbox\mymeasure{some text}` before the `\hspace`, and then use `\hspace{\wd\mymeasure}`

Comment: @tohecz Is there a way to put the saving of the box inside the macro?

Comment: No, `\hspace{#1}`, as is, internally uses `\kern#1`. The macro `\kern` expands what follows as long as needed to get `<number><unit>`, expanding all `\skip` and `\dimen` (lengths) and `\ht`, `\wd`, `\dp` too (box measurements), then it continues looking for `plus` or `minus` part of the skip. Since `\sbox` is not expandable, `\kern` complains that it has not found the skip value yet and hit a non-expandable barrier.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\findwidth[1]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\the\wd0}
This text is how long? \findwidth{This text is how long?}
\par\rule{\wd0}{1ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX has a standard `\settowidth` command for saving the width of some known text in advance, The trick `calc` plays is to allow this to be used inline rather than boxing the text first.