# LaTeX command for symbol needed. looks like crossed equal

Tags: symbols

I can’t find the LaTeX command for the symbol below. Can anyone help me out to find this symbol? *I wasn't able to find it with Detexify.*

[image]

Comment: what does this symbol mean?

Comment: To the voters for closing as duplicate: before doing this one should ensure that the symbol *can* be found with those means.

Comment: @egreg In case of these ever-returning symbol questions, I'd rather close any that doesn't state explicitly that the OP already tried Detexify.

Comment: @lockstep So, before voting, ask the OP.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well here is one that looks kinda like cheating, it uses `amsmath` only, though adding `calc` will make the definition much simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\crossl}
\settowidth{\crossl}{$\times$}
\newlength{\ceql}
\settowidth{\ceql}{$\times=$}
\addtolength{\ceql}{-\crossl}
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrel{\makebox[\crossl][l]{$\times\hspace{-\ceql}=$}}}

\begin{document}
$f(x)\crosseq g(x)\crosseq h(x)$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

One can also play around with the position and the symbols used:

```
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrel{\makebox[7.7778pt][l]{$\neq$\hspace{-6.7778pt}\raisebox{-2.5pt}{$\backslash$}}}}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Since this answer is chose I will add some more solution, this time using egreg's suggestion as poking around with boxes will likely create unexpected spacing issue:

```
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hidewidth$/$\hidewidth\cr\ooalign{\hidewidth$\backslash$\hidewidth\cr$=$\cr}\cr}}}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hidewidth$/$\hidewidth\cr\ooalign{\hidewidth\raisebox{-2pt}{$\backslash$}\hidewidth\cr$=$\cr}\cr}}}
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT2:** Add `[l]` option to `\makebox` in order to adjust alignment.

Comment: Why `\DeclareMathOperator`? I'd say it's a `\mathrel`. However, `\mathrel{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\times$\hidewidth\cr$=$\cr}}` is simpler.

Comment: @egreg: good call, it should be a relation.

Answer (score 23):

Depending on your usage, the following may suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\neq$\cr\reflectbox{$\neq$}\cr}}}
\begin{document}
$f(x) = g(x) \neq h(x) \crosseq i(x)$
\end{document}
```

The symbol `\crosseq` consists of an overlay of `\neq` and a reflected `\neq`. For a short lesson in `\ooalign` and symbol overlaying, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

Comment: hi its not  working here Werner. it displays 2 \neq nearer only,,,

Comment: @ravi: Do you receive errors? Did you include the `graphicx` package? Did you copy it correctly? What "[is] not working"?

Comment: i copied the above entire code and paste it in tex file and run it.  im not getting the exact output what displayed here

Comment: @ravi: I'm using one of the basic packages/tools (`graphicx`) and compiling under `pdflatex`. Note that `\crosseq` can only be used in math mode. Are you getting an error or a warning?

Answer (score 15):

Just for a change, no `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}

% make \widthof usable with \hspace
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99242
\makeatletter
\def\@hspace#1{\begingroup\setlength\dimen@{#1}\hskip\dimen@\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\rnot}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \text{%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \hspace{\widthof{$=$}}\reflectbox{$\not$}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\crosseq}{\rnot\not=}

\begin{document}
$a\crosseq b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nicer than the first answer, and especially than the one based on `xcancel` as the cross is vertically centred on the = sign

Answer (score 15):

You might consider using the `cancel` package.  Its command `\xcancel` places a cross over any given symbol.  For a relation symbol like `=` you should enclose the whole construct in `\mathrel` to get the correct horizontal spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand{\cancelledeq}{\mathrel{\xcancel{=}}}

\begin{document}

\( a = b \cancelledeq c \)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Poor man's code (simplified and stolen from egreg's):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\newcommand{\crosseq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \text{%
        {$\neq$\reflectbox{$\not$}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$a\crosseq b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

on the theory that there was some meaning to the asymmetry of the original drawing, and stealing egreg's very nice name for the symbol, here's another approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\crosseq}{\mathrlap{{}\mathrel{\smallsetminus}{}}\not=}

\begin{document}
$a\crosseq b$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]