# Insert negative of \widthof into \hspace without defining a newlength

Tags: horizontal-alignment, calculations

Following MWE does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\charwidth}
\setlength{\charwidth}{\widthof{$-$}}
\begin{document}
\centering $\infty$

\centering \hspace{-\charwidth}$-\infty$

\centering \hspace{-\widthof{$-$}}$-\infty$
\end{document}
```

`\hspace{-\widthof{$-$}}` throws following error

> `! Missing number, treated as zero.
>   <to be read again>
>                      \widthof
>   l.10 \centering \hspace{-\widthof{$-$}}
>                                          $-\infty$
>   ?`

Is there a possibility to insert negative `\widthof` into `\hspace` without defining a newlength?

Comment: I think we just forgot `\hspace` when adding `calc` support to the rest of the format back when we made 2e. You can use the scratch register `0` if you don't want to define a new length `\setlength{\dimen0}{-\widthof{$-$}}\hspace{\dimen0}`

Comment: Just accept that you cannot. `calc` goes through several hoops in order to get `\withof` to work inside `\setlength`, so it is no wonder that it will not work in other everyday circumstances.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: While one add can the support for `\widthof` to hspace (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99242/2388), the negative `-\widthof{..}` doesn't work -- neither in the `\setlength` nor elsewhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hmm we should fix calc then :(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle perhaps the Q's title should be modified because already `\hspace{\widthof{$-$}}` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is valid in TexLive 2019 and 2013, but not in 2016. Use it at your own risk.

I just tweaked @DavidCarlisle answer. Instead of just defining the `-widthof{$-$}`, I substracted it from zero `0pt-widthof{$-$}`
(it should yield the same ;))

So here is the way to get negative lengths from the `\width_` commands
`\setlength{\dimen0}{0pt-\widthof{$-$}}\hspace{\dimen0}`

So your code would look like that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\charwidth}
\setlength{\charwidth}{\widthof{$-$}}
\begin{document}
   \centering $\infty$

   \centering \hspace{-\charwidth}$-\infty$

  \centering \setlength{\dimen0}{0pt-\widthof{$-$}}\hspace{\dimen0}$-\infty$
\end{document}
```

Technically no new length is defined as David pointed out, although the scratch register is used.

God bless you, guys.

> Edition: result image added

[image]

Comment: The output doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: Hey @Werner, I added the picture of my output (TeXstudio 2.11.0 + TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013) kpathsea version 6.1.1 Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.)   I think everything is ok. :)

Comment: If you update to TeX Live 2016, the output doesn't match what you show. It may store historic value, but not for current distributions.

Comment: Well, then it is a 'historic answer', only valid for TeX Live 2013. :\

Comment: It worked for me on TeX Live 2019 in the normal environment (not math, didn’t tried though).

Comment: @Archange Glad to hear that someone could benefit of my answer! Though it seemed to be obsolete (it got twice -1 ;)) at last it worked for good.