# Negative `\widthof` doesn't work?

Tags: spacing, width, lengths, calc, setlength

I am basically reasking the same question as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257461/insert-negative-of-widthof-into-hspace-without-defining-a-newlength), which hasn't had any definitive answer even yet.

I restate the problem. The MWE

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
    \hspace{-\widthof{abc}}
\end{document}
```

produces the following errors:

```
6: Missing number, treated as zero. \hspace{-\widthof{abc}}
6: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \hspace{-\widthof{abc}}
6: Package calc Error: `\widthof ' invalid at this point. \hspace{-\widthof{abc}}
```

**Questions:**

1. `\hspace` surely does take negative values and `\widthof` does produce lengths, so why doesn't it work?
2. Is there a way to achieve what is intended without resorting to the tedious `\newlength` and `setlength`?

Comment: `calc` needs to parse for the `\widthof` and then alters the way `\hspace` works (there is no expandable way to get the width of arbitrary text, afaik), and seemingly `calc` didn't implement `-\widthof` in its parser, so not much you can do about it, other than using `\newlength\mytmplength\newcommand\hspaceNegWd[1]{\settowidth\mytmplength{#1}\hspace{-\wd\mytmplength}}`.

Comment: Of course, it's easier if you say `\makebox[0pt][l]{abc}`, instead of backing up by the width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is contained in the referenced duplicate but somewhat hidden as at the time that question was asked `\hspace` did not support `calc` at all, so even `\hspace{1pt+2pt}` would have failed.

Unary minus is not implemented for `\widthof` however infix subtraction is, so you can subtract from 0pt:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

abc\hspace{0pt-\widthof{abc}}xyz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another (equivalent) way would be `\widthof{abc}*-1`.

Comment: @Marijn yes, or we could make unary minus work in calc:-) but I don't really want to touch the calc code